# Reading XEL (SQL Server eXtended Event file) by log collectors such as filebeats or nxlog

Tags: sql-server, filebeat, graylog2, nxlog, extended-events

I want to create a centralized log with `graylog` and log collectors such as `filebeats` or `nxlogs`.
I know `Microsoft SQL Server extended events` creates .XEL files. but they are binary files.

Is there any clean way to read this xel files by `filebeats` or `nxlog` or any other tools and send it to graylog?

Comment: You can use the [.NET QueryableXEventData class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq.queryablexeventdata) to read xel files programmatically in .NET code or PowerShell script. For your needs, I think it would be easiest to create a text file from the XE data for ingestion by your tools.

Answer (score 3):

With nxlog you could use the im_exec module and write a script (as suggested by @dan-guzman) that would convert the .xel files into a text based format. 
The other option could be using the [Event Tracing for Windows Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/event-tracing-for-windows-target?view=sql-server-2017) with the [im_etw](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/im_etw.html) input module to can collect ETW events.

Comment: I have bee trying to set up the im_etw module and basically everything seems to be alright but I'm not getting any output from ncLog. nxLog is working as I get output from e.g. sql server error log. I have been trying with different providers without any success. Do you know which etw provider you should use with extended events?